# MessageBox showing behind Popup in UserControl

Tags: wpf, z-index, messagebox

I've a UserControl in my WPF app that creates a `Popup`. A button on the `Popup` creates a `MessageBox`, but the `MessageBox` is showing up behind the `Popup`. I've tried setting the `Panel.ZIndex` on the `Popup`, but that isn't making a difference. I can't really change who the parent window is on the `MessageBox` because I have only one window, unless there's some way to set the parent to my `Popup` control?
Does anybody know how to remedy my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I hate WPF's built-in popup. One of my biggest pet peeves with it is that it gets drawn on top of all other windows (which includes windows that are not part of the WPF application)

As an alternative, I have [created my own Popup for WPF](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) which is just a UserControl that can be added to your main Visual Tree.

Comment: I'm somewhat new to WPF, and I'm having problems using your control. It won't let me have named controls (ComboBox/etc) inside of the Content of the PopupPanel. I need these to get some values and whatnot.

Comment: @G_M I forgot about that... I usually bind the `Content` to a data object and set the `ContentTemplate` or `DataTemplate` for the object, but one time I was trying to add content directly to the Popup and go the same error. It had something to do with WPF not allowing you to name controls that are part of a UserControl's content. I would recommend using the `ContentTemplate` to define the popup template, although a workaround I did use once was to attach the Name during the `Loaded` event of the control. I always meant to find a better solution but haven't gotten around to it yet.